# Can't ssh into EC2 instance if I set my user to sudo: true in cloud-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

The following yml script initiates an EC2 instance which allows me to login with the .pem file corresponding to the `ssh_authorized_keys`.

```
  - name: myuser                                                                
    primary_group: mygroup                                                       
    sudo: false                                                                
    lock_passwd: true                                                          
    ssh_authorized_keys:                                                       
      - ssh-rsa ALDLKDSDF...
```

However, if I set `sudo: true`, the instance won't let me ssh (authentication failed). The same is true if I also set `lock_passwd: false`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Cloud config examples — cloud-init documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html):

```
#   sudo: Defaults to none. Accepts a sudo rule string, a list of sudo rule
#         strings or False to explicitly deny sudo usage. Examples:
#
#         Allow a user unrestricted sudo access.
#             sudo:  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
#
#         Adding multiple sudo rule strings.
#             sudo:
#               - ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/mysql
#               - ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#         Prevent sudo access for a user.
#             sudo: False
#
#         Note: Please double check your syntax and make sure it is valid.
#               cloud-init does not parse/check the syntax of the sudo
#               directive.
```

Therefore, **there is no `true` option for `sudo`**.

Comment: ‍♂️ thanks, not enough coffee